# Contao CMS adding files from the frontend

Tags: php, contao

I'm using Contao CMS 3.5.x, I have successfully added an "enclosure" on the backend (DCA). Now I need my frontend user (member) to upload a doc from the frontend (and save it in the same db field). How can I do this from a frontend point of view?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could create a form via the form generator that writes into your desired table. However, Contao only stores the relative file path of uploaded files into the database - but you probably want an UUID there.

You can use [fritzmg/contao-store-uuid](https://github.com/fritzmg/contao-store-uuid) to automatically store the UUID for file fields.

Comment: Ok, thanks for this, but how should I integrate it from frontend? Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you mean? You can create a form with the form generator. In the options of that form you can specify, that the data from that successfully submitted form should be stored in a specific database table.

Comment: Hello, I mean how to use it? I want to add a "upload your doc field" on the frontend and the upload should be stored on the same "enclosure" field that is defined on the DCA. I copied your "store_uuid" in the /modules folder and then what should I do?

Comment: You need to provide more information in your original post. Provide more info on your table for example and how it relates to the user and what exactly you want to accomplish.